# Tilda terminal emulator malfunction

Tags: 18.04, tilda

I had Tilda installed and working just fine. I then installed Zsh in an attempt to see which GIT branch I am currently checked out into.
Zsh didn't work out for me so I used `sudo apt-get remove --purge zsh -y` to remove it.

After uninstalling Zsh, Tilda malfunctioned. It presents a prompt, no text and does not accept any input.

I have uninstalled using `sudo apt-get remove --purge tilda -y` and re-installed Tilda but it made no difference.

Even after purging it from the system, Ubuntu reuses the same settings after I have re-installed.

The screen shot below shows my Tilda HUD instance. It might be hard to see why I included it but the top left hand corner shows the promt. Other than that, Tilda is suddenly and inexplicably useless.

I need help, please.

[image]

Comment: Did you log out and then back in?

Comment: @vanadium: Yes! Multiple times and it made no difference

Comment: Then you may need to change your shell manually back to bash: `chsh -s /bin/bash`.

Comment: @vanadium: Tried that and the issue remains the same

Answer (score 0):

The `--purge` option will remove config files installed system-wide by APT itself. But there are also per-user config files created by Tilda. On my system (20.04.1), I can see:

```
$ find ~ -iname \*tilda\*
~/.config/autostart/tilda.desktop
~/.config/tilda
~/.cache/tilda
```

In `~/.config/tilda`, you should see several files starting with `config_`, these are different versions of Tilda's preference. You may try a diff between these files and look for something related to zsh.

Also, after you've quit tilda, you can safely remove `~/.cache/tilda`, then restart tilda and hope that it will fix your problem...

Comment: Thanks Giles. 
I found all the files you indicated. I uninstalled Tilda then deleted all the related files in all 3 of those directories. When I restarted, the previously use settings were all gone BUT is still unuseable. Still presents nothing more than a prompt and accepts no input.

Comment: Can you confirm that other terminal emulator are not affected by the problem? If you run Ubuntu's default "Terminal" application, does it work fine?

Comment: @Giles Bassiere: Yes, the default terminal is working just fine. I would just use the default terminal but it will make my work flow slower and far less efficient.

Comment: Bind your terminal to a hotkey like `sh -c "wmctrl -x -a Gnome-terminal || gnome-terminal", and your workflow will be like with tilda or better. Still, strange how purging everything does not rescue tilda to life on your system.

Comment: @vanadium: I just tried that command but it resulted in a newline with a greated-than symbol indicating the command is incomplete. Can you help me understand how I can use that to configure a hotkey for terminal? Also, I don't see where in that command to specify my hotkey value.

Comment: You need to include the end " in the command. Bind this command to a shortcut key (Settings - Keyboard Shortcuts in standard Ubuntu).

Comment: @vanadium: I didn't realise I missed the end character. Thanks